# Continuously looping, unable to work out what's going wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, proxy, mechanize

My code below isn't working how I want it to, I've tried to comment it a little to make it easier.

Basically, I want it to try a maximum of three times to access the website and if it is successful it will exit the loop and continue, if it fails three times it will exit out of the function.

```
import random
import urllib2
import httplib
import urllib
import mechanize

def test():

    ## For three attempts...
    for i in range(0, 3):
        ## While in the three attempts...
        while True:
            ## Try...
            try:
                print "trying"
                ## Proxy list
                proxy_list = {"No Proxy": "None"}

                ## Randomly chosen proxy
                proxy_number = random.choice(proxy_list.keys())

                ## URL to post to in order to get data.
                post_url = ""

                browser = mechanize.Browser()
                browser.set_handle_robots(False)
                browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
                parameters = {""}
                data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)

                ## If proxy_number = No Proxy then...
                if proxy_number == "No Proxy":
                    ## Do not setup proxy details
                    proxy_details = None
                ## If proxy_number is a real proxy then...
                else:
                    ## Get the proxy details
                    proxy_details = proxy_list[proxy_number]
                    ## Setup the proxy
                    browser.set_proxies({"http": proxy_number})

                ## Contact the webpage
                trans_array = browser.open(post_url).read().decode('UTF-8')
                print trans_array
                ## If successfully exit loop
                break
            ## On exceptions
            except:
                ## If unsuccessful continue and retry
                continue
            ## End the current loop
        break
            ## If it was unsuccessful after three attempts return false
        return

    print trans_array

test()
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: For falsetru

```
def test():
    for i in range(3):
        try:
            ...
            break
    except:
        counter = counter  + 1
        print counter 
        continue

    if counter  == 3:
        return False
```

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Comment: It seems to me that because you continue on exceptions, if an exception occurs every time, the while loop will infinitely execute

Comment: Your while loop will always be true and the for loop will never make it past range 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If error occur, `continue` is executed; `while` loop never end if error continuously raised.

```
def test():
    for i in range(0, 3):
        while True:
            try:
                ...
                break
            except:
                continue # <---
        break
```

IMHO, `while` loop is unnecessary:

```
def test():
    for i in range(3):
        try:
            ...
            break
        except:
            continue
    else:
        return # Reach here if for loop was not ended by break
    print trans_array
```

Comment: Hey @falsetru so how can I make your fixed example exit out of the function after the third fail?

Comment: @Hyflex, Using `for i in range(3):`, it does not run more than three time.

Comment: @falsetrue, yeah I understand that part but I want it to be able to exit the function after the third fail but if it doesn't fail it will skip below. See my edit

Comment: @Hyflex, What is the **below**? `print trans_array`?

Comment: yeah I don't quite understand how it's able to continue and be able to exit if the 3 trys fail...

Comment: @Hyflex, You can use `for .. else ..` statement. See updated code.

Comment: Thank you ever so much, I found a hacky way round too :P see my edited code for my hacky way but I'm using your method.

Thank you ever so much :)